# What was the recent 3 week delay for?

Tags: scheduling

I watch shows like Pawn Stars, American Restoration and Count's Customs on History channel. Recently (as in 2-3 weeks ago) they announced the shows would "return in 3 weeks" and have not aired an episode since. Archer (FX channel) did the same thing. I don't regularly watch other shows so I have no idea if any others followed suit.

I understood when American Horror Story: Coven took a break during the holiday season, but not this.

So why the 3 week delay?

Comment: Several shows are on a hiatus due to the __Winter Olympics__.

Comment: I completely forgot about the Olympics!

Comment: @Oliver_C ... That's the reason. You should make an answer as such.

Comment: @Oliver_C i am not fan of this kind of question but i am sure your comment is an answer.

Comment: Not really a question about any specific show or technique, just more of a, "Why is my favorite show not currently running new episodes?" Doesn't really add anything of value to the site.

Comment: @MattD has nothing to do about "my favorite shows". I ask about the reasoning behind networks scheduling delays into their broadcasting timelines during a specific period of time. I just happen to use shows that I watch as example/reference.

Comment: @MattD but knowing the answer is the Olympics, my question does seem too localized/specific to add value to the site as a whole.

Comment: @DustinDavis Which could still result in numerous reasons, but the primary one of which would be the Olympics are on because that's the most timely. Another comment even feels this type of question doesn't really belong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The break coincides with the Winter Olympics, and allows them to air new episodes when they have a better chance of beating their competition for viewership, which (in turn) allows them to charge more for advertising.